# Error trying to create a violin plot

Tags: r

I have a file with one column and approximately 45 milion lines of numeric data.

I would like to generate a violin plot but I'm receiving the following error from R:

```
Error in [.data.frame(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, 
 decreasing = decreasing)) : undefined columns selected
```

My R script is quite simple, as follows:

```
library(vioplot)
data <- read.table("my-file-path")
vioplot(data)
```

Does anyone know why that error happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to specify the column of the data.frame `data` that you want your violin plot of. Further help may only be given if you provide a working example, e.g. give the output of `dput(data[1:10,])`.

Comment: If your data has one column, then `unlist(data)` should work. `vioplot(unlist(data))`, but the better method to select the column with `vioplot(data$COLUMNNAME).` Additionally, I think `geom_violin` from `ggplot2` is more aesthetically pleasing than `library(vioplot)`

Comment: either of these comments could be answers ...

Comment: vioplot(unlist(data)) worked well. thanks.

Comment: Bruno, could you please post that as an answer?

Comment: no problem... I just don't understand why my question received -3 votes, once it was legitimate.

Comment: probably 'lack of research effort'. The confusion is understandable, but also one that most not-super-beginners in R would have figured out for themselves by knowing a little bit more about how R handles data.  By the way, you can *probably* import your data as a simple vector by using `scan()` rather than `read.table()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Vlo told in the comments, the following modification worked well:

```
vioplot(unlist(data))
```

Comment: As would have `vioplot(data[[1]])` or `vioplot( data[[names(data)]])`